# Unable to connect to ejabberd server with Adium

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, adium

I have installed ejabberd 20.02 with homebrew (Mac OS Catalina). When trying to connect to ejabberd server with Adium I receive this error message in the ejabberd log. I am not sure how to proceed.

[image: Error in the ejabberd log file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like ejabberd is forced to use TLS/SSL on C2S connections but you did not give it a correct certificate for the host, the client is trying to connect to. One way to solve this would be to get a valid cert for your host. For example you can get them for free from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). The other way to solve it would be allowing unsecured c2s connections, but I wouldn't recommend this. It could be done by setting `starttls_required` to false on the c2s listener as described in the [docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#options)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the TLS/SSL requirement by setting the `starttls_required` to `false` in the ejabberd.yml

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: false
```